# Can't run batch file from runas command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, runas

I'm trying to open a file using runas command from cmd.

I succeed when i run it like this:

```
file.bat
```

or like this:

```
start file.bat
```

but when i run:

```
runas /user:username file.bat
```

the file opens but closes immediately (I'm entering the right password).
I know that for sure that I'm entering the right password and that the batch file opens and closes without executing its content.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to get the `runas` command to run in the same window. But a trick is to spawn the cmd window yourself with the /k switch to prevent it from closing when done:

`runas /user:username "cmd /k {fullpath}\file.bat"`

Note that you need the full path to the file because the new window opens to your user directory.

Or you just put `pause` at the end of your .bat file instead of doing the above.

Answer (score 0):

Use PsExec instead (MS SysInternals suite). Much better and secure (password used).

psexec -user Administrator -p Passwd "xcopy file.bat {fullpath}\file.bat"