# Run a cmd command in batch script as an Administrator without UAC prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, winrm

I have a batch file with various commands. I am transferring the batch file to a remote PC and running the file. Now I need to run a few of the commands in the batch file as an administrator but I cannot go to the remote PC to enter any password or click on any prompt.
My batch file includes the following commands:

```
1. winrm quickconfig -force
2. winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
3. winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
```

Now the commands 2 and 3 needs to be run as an administrator. I have the admin password. Is there any command arguments like

```
"command" /runas /user:admin /pass:password /noprompt
```

Using only /runas still gives you a prompt and there is no option in runas /? that can disable it. I need a solution where I don't have to press Yes on the UAC prompt since the file will run on a remote system.

Edit: Would like to give more context. So the task is to automate the process of running configuration script on remote machine once windows is installed on it. There would be approximately 100 machines and going on each system and enabling the winrm service is not feasible. And in order to run the script remotely on the target machine, I need to enable and then make changes to the winrm service (needs admin privileges). I cannot make changes to the network. I am able to enable winrm service but making changes to winrm service requires running those commands as admin. And I cannot click on any prompt since I cannot go to the remote machine. So any advice in this regards would be helpful. I'm not trying to bypass any process. I have the admin credentials. Just trying to find the correct commands and arguments to help me achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't run batch file from runas command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733752/cant-run-batch-file-from-runas-command)

Comment: Yes, there is such a command. Use the command `RUNAS /?` to read all about it. There are -many- questions and answers already on SO regarding this.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. Using only /runas still gives you a prompt and there is no option in runas /? that can disable it. I need a solution where I don't have to press Yes on the UAC prompt since the file will run on a remote system.

Comment: Type `wmic /node:ComputerName /User:user /Password:pass Process Call Create C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe C:\\MyBatch.bat`. For Help type `/?` after everything - ie `wmic /node /?`, wmic process call /?`, or `wmic process call create /?`.